# Hosting WCF service inside web project

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm trying to create a wcf service inside a c# mvc web project. I've added a new item of type "WCF Service" and added a test method in the provided Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITest
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork();

    bool testWorking();
}
```

And the provided service:

```
public class Test : ITest
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
    }

    public bool testWorking()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And I've then gone over to the web.config file and added the following to the system.ServiceModel tag:

```
 <services>
      <service name="Test" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ITest">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex"  binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

At this point, as I understand it, I should be able to view this in a browser and get a test message telling me that it's about time I implemented a client to use this service. However what actually happens is that my browser downloads the .svc file!

Two questions:

1) What the hell am I doing wrong? Why am I not seeing the expected message?

2) Is there any way I can automatically start the WCF testing tool to run on this service? The only guidelines I can find are for starting from a WCF project.

*Update:* (content of svc file - grabbed from comment)

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
    Service="myemployersaddress.com.Test" CodeBehind="Test.svc.cs" %>
```

Comment: Are you hosting the service in IIS? Looks like you don't have installed correct handlers for .svc. Also be aware that service's name attribute and endpoint's contract attribute must contain type names with namespaces included - but it is not source of your current problem.

Comment: I did wonder about the namespaces - figured that since it was hosted in the same project they weren't necessary but thanks for the clarification. I'm running this in IIS using the default server provided by Visual Studio ... not entirely sure how one would go about installing the correct handlers for that if they're not there.

Comment: The `Service=...` in your SVC file should **also** reference the fully qualified name of your service **class** - e.g. `Service=YourNamespace.Test`. Is that the case in your svc file?? The service entry here isn't any kind of a web URL or anything like that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've described you should be fine, but since you're not:

1. What server are you using? IIS, cassini?
2. What is the contents of the svc file that you download? (open it in notepad)

To start the test tool from inside visual studio, right click on the .svc file and 'set as start page' and then hit f5. That should open the test tool and allow you to inspect your service. That should give you some clues as to what the problem is.

Comment: 1) IIS, 2) It's the ASP.NET headers for the markup in the .svc service, to whit <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="myemployersaddress.com.Test" CodeBehind="Test.svc.cs" %> ... and if I set it as start page and hit f5 my website starts and ... downloads the .svc file.

Comment: @Matt Thrower: please don't put stuff like this into a comment - it's next to impossible to read.... instead: update your original question with the additional info by editing it (as I did for you in this case) - that's much easier on the eyes !

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a web-server configuration issue;

- is the application marked as an application in IIS (does it have a cog)? - it should
- is the application configured to use the correct version of ASP.NET (i.e. not 1.x)
- is .NET 3.0 or above installed on the server?
- does the framework master web.config contain the .svc mappings?

re the last, I've seen a glitch here where the install **doesn't touch the config at all** if it isn't quite how it expected to find it; so if you have manually changed the master web.config on the server you may need to apply the 3.0 changes manually

for example, in `<buildProviders>` you should have something like (for 3.0):

```
<add extension=".svc" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceBuildProvider, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
```

in `<httpHandlers>` you should have something like (for 3.0):

```
<add path="*.svc" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" validate="false"/>
```

and there should be a host of extra things in `<compilation>/<assemblies>`, such as:

```
<add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL"/>
<add assembly="System.IdentityModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL"/>
<add assembly="System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
<add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
<add assembly="System.WorkflowServices, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

this is just from a quick scan - there may be others, and the exact values may change per environment.

Comment: Curiously there is already an svc service added under httpHandlers - it's version 2 and it's mapped to a particular .svc rather than *.svc ... but none of the other stuff is there.

Comment: @Matt - first, check that .NET 3.0 is actually *installed* on the server; you might be able to just install it. The manual fixup is only if it is there but didn't update the .config

Comment: @Matt: And emphasis: this is the **master** web.config, so for ASP.NET 2.x, %systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\web.config

Comment: BTW I'm running this locally under Visual Studio's local development server version of IIS. I kind of assumed all this was installed by default. And I don't seem to have a master web config.

Comment: Sure you do - in the framework folder... if you only have .NET 4.0 then just start from %systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework ;p